# What is the equivalent of clear or cls in TempleOS?

Tags: shell, reset, templeos

Sometimes my cursor gets lost in a muck of text in the scrollback buffer, or I have graphics created with calls like `GrLine(,100,100,200,150);` that I would like to clear.

What command or system call clears the screen? I've tried `reset`, `clear`, and `cls` and `DCClear` (*Device Context - Clear*) sets my screen to black.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two methods of clearing the screen,

- Typing `$CL$` and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, or executing function that prints that sequence such as `DocClear;` as defined in [`Adam/DolDoc/DocRecalcLib.HC.Z`](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Adam/DolDoc/DocRecalcLib.html)
- Running `DCFill;` to clear things drawn to the screen such as the `Gr`. `DCFill;` is defined in [`Adam/Gr/GrDC.HC.Z`](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Adam/Gr/GrDC.html). This essentially fills (`DCFill;`) the device context (DC) with transparent pixels.

---

Alternatively you can reinitialize a new terminal, replacing your old one this can be done a few ways.

- `DocTermNew;`, all functions call `DocTermNew;` which replaces your terminal with another process. This is defined in [`Adam/DolDoc/DolDoc.HC.Z`](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Adam/DolDoc/DocTerm.html).
- `User;`, which is defined in [`Kernel/KTask.HC.Z`](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Kernel/KTask.html)
- Term initializers in the form of `SrvStartUp;` and `UserStartUp;` both of which are defined in [`HomeSys.HC.Z`](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/HomeSys.html) (all of these wrap  with

  - `SrvStartUp;` is the bare minimal to initialize the text screen.
  - `UserStartUp;` essentially does a `SrvStartUp;` and puts `./Doc/Start.DD` onto the screen, and runs `Dir;`